# Oreo custom notification sound for each notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

Since Android 8 notification channels required for notifications. Sounds can be set for each notification channel (by user in settings or by an application). But let's say I want 10 different sounds for notifications? Create 10 notification channels? Not a good idea. Any solutions?